# Copiar datos en un excel sólo sobre filas filtradas

Tags: excel, filtro

Tengo dos columnas en excel y filtro según un parámetro en concreto y sobre esas filas filtradas me gustaría copiar unos datos extraídos de otro fichero.

El problema es que no me sobrescribe solo las columnas visibles al filtrar, sino que me sobrescribe en las filas ocultas debido al filtro.

¿Cómo podría solucionar esto?

Gracias!

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: el error esta el la linea #256 del codigo

Answer (score 0):

te dejo u ejemplo,

muestra original
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

filtro col 1 con valores > 5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego vas a Incicio >> Buscar y seleccionar >> Ir a especial...
ahi seleccionas solo celdas visibles

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y ya se copia y pega lo visible

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]